# How to distinguish a terminal window currently connected via SSH?

Tags: terminal, ssh

I'm coming from Windows, where I used to use Putty whenever I needed to connect to a server via SSH.

On MacOS this is much easier, as I can `ssh` into the server directly from the terminal. This is nice, but comes with a caveat: I might have a few terminal windows open at the same time, and mistake a terminal opened locally with a terminal `ssh`'ed into a remote server (and make nasty mistakes).

**Is there any way I can visually distinguish a terminal window connected via ssh, from another one on my local machine?**

Comment: Look to the title of the window, or the title of the tab if you are using several tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Look to the title of the window, or the title of the tab if you are using several tabs:

[image]

> That won't be enough for me to avoid making mistakes  – Benjamin
>
> I was thinking about something like the window changing color somewhere. Don't even know if that's technically possible, though. – Benjamin

Assuming a worst case when you are unable to change remote's prompt, edit you mac's terminal prompt in order to make most clear if the terminal is at a client of a Mac of yours.

If you use Tmux, configure non defaults `status-fg` `status-bg` so that your Mac's local terminals use a different Tmux color than what is configured at your servers.

Comment: That won't be enough for me to avoid making mistakes 

Comment: I was thinking about something like the window changing color somewhere. Don't even know if that's technically possible, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to set-up [powerline](https://github.com/powerline/powerline), you could have a prompt which shows if you are currently logged into a ssh session. This would be hard to miss. [image]